# Adding FirebaseUI/Storage pod to iOS App throws framework not found SDWebImage for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, firebase, sdwebimage, firebase-storage, firebaseui

I am trying to add FirebaseUI/Storage pod to iOS App which is throwing the following linker error:

> framework not found SDWebImage for architecture x86_64

I have tried adding SDWebImage independently and it works but as soon as I add FirebaseUI/Storage pod, it throws the above error.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

This is what my Podfile looks like:

```
target 'myApp' do

pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'

pod 'FirebaseUI/Storage'

pod 'SDWebImage'
pod 'MMDrawerController'

end
```

Comment: Mind sharing some more information (Podfile, `pod install` output, version numbers, etc.)?

Comment: You shouldn't need the second `SDWebImage` as it should be pulled in automatically from `FirebaseUI/Storage`. What version of CocoaPods are you using? Also, is this Obj-C or Swift? Do you have `use_frameworks!` if you need it (are using Swift).

Comment: I am using the latest version of CocoaPods. This is Obj-C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this exact same problem. I seem to have fixed it by changing my pod file to...

```
target 'MyApp' do
  # Uncomment this line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MyApp
  pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.8'
  # pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'FirebaseUI', '~> 1.0'

  target 'MyAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'MyAppUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

A few things to note:

1. I turned on use_frameworks even though I am using Objective C
2. I turned off my Firebase pod calls - they are pulled in automatically by FirebaseUI

Comment: This seems to be an issue in CocoaPods. SDWebImage is correctly included if you omit `use_frameworks!`, but pods adds linker flags that then expect SDWebImage to be present in framework form. See https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/issues/194

Comment: You saved my day. It works if you uncomment 'use_frameworks!'

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is no clear documentation regarding which pods to include to enable just the FirebaseUI/Storage functionality if also including other individual Firebase/... pods.

I needed to remove all pods and install them back without FirebaseUI/Storage since it duped several classes which were not removed once I removed the [FirebaseUI/Storage] pod.